# Unable to export system.object in a readable form using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, export

I've looked through other answers and I am still struggling. I have some data that comes from a RESTAPI and I get that data using `Invoke-RestMethod` so it is already converted from the returned JSON

`$scans = Invoke-RestMethod -URI "https://<url>/api/v1/<api key>/scans"`

I get back an object with two fields

```
Message:
Data:
```

`$Scans.Data` contains a hash table converted from the JSON output with each entry in the table having the following key:value pairs

```
ScanID
Username
Targets
Name
```

This is the output of `$scans | Get-Member`

```
$scans | gm

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
name        NoteProperty string name=<redacted>
scan_id     NoteProperty string scan_id=<redacted>
targets     NoteProperty Object[] targets=System.Object[]
user_name   NoteProperty string user_name=<redacted>
```

I need to export all data into a CSV, but `$scan.data.targets` only shows as `System.Object[]`

I can't use `-expandproperty` because I am selecting multiple fields.

How do I convert `$scans.data.targets` into a readable form for the export, whilst keeping it linked with the other fields for that entry?

something equivalent to:

`$scans.data | export-CSV <filepath>`

but exporting in a format that is readable when I open the CSV

Comment: How about `Out-String`? Does the `Convertto-Csv` not help in this situation? So you're just trying to export whatever is in `$scans.data`?

Comment: You could also opt to combine the objects separated by a self-chosen delimiter, so they will occupy only one field in the CSV: `$scan.data | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'targets'; Expression = {$_.targets -join '; '}} -ExcludeProperty targets | Export-Csv -Path <filepath> -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you could opt for a combined field of targets in the output:

```
# demo
$scan = [PsCustomObject]@{data = [PsCustomObject]@{name = 'blah'; scan_id = 123; targets = 'abc','def','ghi'; user_name = 'ItIsMe'}}

$scan.data | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'targets'; Expression = {$_.targets -join '; '}} -ExcludeProperty targets | 
             Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\blah.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

which (when displayed in the console) looks like this:

```
name scan_id user_name targets      
---- ------- --------- -------      
blah     123 ItIsMe    abc; def; ghi
```

Or create output where every target gets its own row in the CSV:

```
$result = foreach ($item in $scan.data) {
    foreach ($target in $item.targets) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Name     = $item.name
            ScanID   = $item.scan_id
            Target   = $target
            UserName = $item.user_name
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$result

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\blah.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

which gives you this:

```
Name ScanID Target UserName
---- ------ ------ --------
blah    123 abc    ItIsMe  
blah    123 def    ItIsMe  
blah    123 ghi    ItIsMe
```

Comment: Thank you ... Just what I was trying to do (first example). I knew I could do something along those lines, I just couldn't put it together. Thanks